# CDI and WELD in java-web-start APP (java se)

Tags: cdi, java-web-start, jboss-weld

Im trying to use CDI in a Java-web-start app but get stuck at classloading. Looks like FileSystemURLHandler treats the URLs in the web-start cache as files.

```
org.jboss.weld.environment.se.discovery.url.FileSystemURLHandler - could not read entries
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\localhost:8080\myapp.jar
```

Which is the same as: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1040

My limited skills in jira and git-hub suggests that someone started working on it, but it didnt make it into a release: https://github.com/agattiker/core/blob/9eabd09f0b8e80e48e3270414e2f68ebc1016b70/environments/se/core/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/environment/se/discovery/url/FileSystemURLHandler.java

So my question is if anyone got around this problem or if cdi+weld on jws is a dead end?

Comment: Looks like there's a pull request, but it hasn't ever been accepted. Try the Weld forums on jboss.org, or #weld-dev on irc.

Comment: I can report back and inform that the changes made on that branch worked well. Didnt observe any negative side-effects yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it is not too late, the issue was fixed in the weld version 2.2.0.Alpha1.

Comment: Dont have the possibility to verify this. But I trust you are right.