# CDI containers with Java-web-start support

Tags: java, ioc-container, cdi, java-web-start

Which CDI containers support to be started using java-web-start?

Comment: Are you trying to inject dependencies from the server's container into the client's webstart classes?  Or are you trying to instantiate a client-side container?

Comment: Im trying to start a client-side container. I ran into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159960/cdi-and-weld-in-java-web-start-app-java-se and thought there might be some container that already supports it